# Как подключить font-face в IE9?

Tags: css3, internet-explorer

IE9 упорно не подхватывает font-face :(
Уже кучу различных методов перепробовал.
Из "хваленых" и "пуленепробиваемых" приведу два:

```
@font-face {
            font-family: 'PFBeauSansPro';
            src: url('font/PFBeauSansPro-Regular.otf'); 
            src: url('font/PFBeauSansPro-Regular.eot?') format('embedded-opentype'), 
                 url('font/PFBeauSansPro-Regular.woff') format('woff'), 
                 url('font/PFBeauSansPro-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'), 
                 url('font/PFBeauSansPro-Regular.svg#PFBeauSansPro') format('svg');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;     
        }

@font-face {
font-family: 'PFBeauSansPro';
src: url('font/PFBeauSansPro-Regular.eot?') format('eot'),
     url('font/PFBeauSansPro-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('font/PFBeauSansPro-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('font/PFBeauSansPro-Regular.svg#PFBeauSansPro') format('svg');
```

}

В IE8 и у всех адекватных браузерах все ОК, IE9 не подключает шрифт.

Answer (score 3):

Иногда стоит воспользоваться поиском, где были [ответы на идентичные вопросы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607560/font-face-works-in-ie8-but-not-ie9). Решение — использование шрифтов и в формате `.woff`, и в `.eot`, при этом в специфическом порядке. Советую воспользоваться генеротарами на подобии [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).